# Multiply two variables in Matlab with vpa - high precision

Tags: matlab, numeric, symbolic-math, arbitrary-precision

I want to be sure that two variables, `a` and `b`, are multiplied with high precision, i.e., perform the product `c` of `a` and `b` with arbitrary precision (in my case 50 correct decimal digits):

```
a = vpa(10/3,50);  
b = vpa(7/13,50);  
c = eval(vpa(vpa(a,50)*vpa(b,50),50));      % I basically want to do just c = a*b;
```

which gives me

```
a = 3.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
b = 0.53846153846153846153846153846153846153846153846154
c = 23.333333333333333333333333333333
```

Testing

```
d = eval(vpa(c*13,50))
```

gives

```
d = 23.333333333333333333333333333333333333335292490585
```

which shows that the multiplication to get `c` was not carried out with 50 significant digits.

What's wrong here, but, more importantly, how do I get a correct result for `a*b` and for other operations such as `exp`?

Answer (score 1):

First, should use `vpa('7/13',50)` or `vpa(7,50)/13` to avoid the possibility of losing precision dues to `7/13` being calculated in double precision floating point (I believe that [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), like `sym`, tries to guess common constants and rational fractions, but you shouldn't rely on it).

The issue is that while `a` and `b` are stored as 50-digit variable precision values, your multiplication is still being performed according to the default value of [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) (32). The second argument to `vpa` only appears to specify the precision of the variable, not any subsequent operations on or with it (the documentation is not particularly helpful in this respect).

One way to accomplish what you want would be:

```
old_digits = digits(50);
a = vpa('10/3')
b = vpa('7/13')
c = a*b
d = 13*c
digits(old_digits);
```

Another would be to use exact symbolic expressions for all of the math (potentially more expensive) and then convert the result to 50-digit variable precision at the end:

```
a = sym('10/3')
b = sym('7/13')
c = a*b
d = vpa(13*c,50)
```

Both methods return `23.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333` for `d`.

Comment: Ok, thanks; just a doubting question: how can I be sure that, in a more complicated computation, vpa actually calculates with 50 decimal digits and not merely shows them, internally representing them as rational fractions or other symbolic expressions? Is there an easy "numeric proof"?

Comment: @Futurist: If your code is correct it should. Your question could be asked about any computation. Ultimately, the only way you can "prove" such a thing to yourself is to know what the answer is ahead of time. More practically, you  can try to perform the same calculation symbolically and/or use a larger value for `digits` to check how the result changes. Or you could perform the calculation other software (I often validate my results in Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha) – in some cases different algorithms can discover (or not) different solutions or may perform the arithmetic differently.

Comment: You can also try bounding your solution using [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) – see the [INTLAB Toolbox](http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/rump/intlab/) for Matlab.